# How to publish a JS package that gracefully fails if an optional peer dependency is not installed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, es6-modules, vite

Is there a way to design a JavaScript package for npm that can dynamically `import()` a third-party npm package, but fail gracefully if that package is not installed as a dependency in the consuming application?

What I want to do is create a React component library that has drag-and-drop capability using `react-dnd`, but only requires `react-dnd` as a dependency if the application utilizes that feature. The `package.json` setup would be something like this:

```json
{
  "name": "my-react-component-lib",
  "devDependencies": {
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dnd": "^16.0.1",
    "react-dnd-html5-backend": "^16.0.1",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0"
  },
  "peerDependecies": {
    "react": ">=16.8.0",
    "react-dnd": "^14.0.0",
    "react-dnd-html5-backend": "^14.0.0"
  },
  "peerDependeciesMeta": {
    "react-dnd": {
      "optional": true
    },
    "react-dnd-html5-backend": {
      "optional": true
    }
  }
}
```

The main component code switches from a basic, non-DnD component tree to a DnD-enabled component tree (using Hooks from `react-dnd`) based on a prop the user provides. Something like this:

```
import { MainComponentBase } from "./MainComponentBase";
import { MainComponentWithDndProvider } from "./MainComponentDnD";
import type { MainComponentProps } from "./types";

export const MainComponent = (props: MainComponentProps) => {
  const key = props.enableDragAndDrop ? "dnd" : "no-dnd";

  if (props.enableDragAndDrop) {
    return <MainComponentWithDndProvider key={key} {...props} />;
  }

  return <MainComponentBase key={key} {...props} />;
};
```

`MainComponentWithDndProvider` runs a custom Hook with a run-only-once `useEffect` that dynamically imports `react-dnd` and sets a state variable containing the `useDrag` and `useDrop` Hooks from that import. Those Hook functions then get passed down to some recursive sub-components that each use them (the non-DnD sub-components do not call them, hence the `key` prop to make sure we avoid calling a different number of Hooks between renders).

Here is the custom Hook, called `useReactDnD`:

```
export type UseReactDnD = typeof import('react-dnd') &
  Pick<typeof import('react-dnd-html5-backend'), 'HTML5Backend'>;

export const useReactDnD = (dndParam?: UseReactDnD) => {
  const [dnd, setDnd] = useState<UseReactDnD | null>(dndParam ?? null);

  useEffect(() => {
    let didCancel = false;

    const getDnD = async () => {
      const [reactDnD, reactDnDHTML5Be] = await Promise.all([
        import('react-dnd').catch(() => null),
        import('react-dnd-html5-backend').catch(() => null),
      ]);

      if (!didCancel) {
        if (reactDnD && reactDnDHTML5Be) {
          setDnd(() => ({ ...reactDnD, HTML5Backend: reactDnDHTML5Be.HTML5Backend }));
        } else {
          // Log a warning to the console about enabling drag-and-drop
          // without installing the necessary dependencies
        }
      }
    };

    if (!dnd) {
      getDnD();
    }

    return () => {
      didCancel = true;
    };
  }, []);

  return dnd;
};
```

And here is the DnD-enabled component:

```
export const MainComponentWithDndProvider = (props: MainComponentProps) => {
  const dnd = useReactDnD(props.dnd);
  const key = dnd ? 'dnd' : 'no-dnd';

  if (!dnd) {
    return <MainComponentBase key={key} {...props} />;
  }

  const { DndProvider, HTML5Backend } = dnd;

  return (
    <DndProvider key={key} backend={HTML5Backend} debugMode={props.debugMode}>
      <MainComponentWithoutDndProvider {...{ ...props, dnd }} />
    </DndProvider>
  );
};
```

(`MainComponentWithoutDndProvider` just wraps `MainComponentBase` in `DndContext.Consumer` and sets up the sub-components.)

If the consuming application decides to utilize the drag-and-drop feature of `my-react-component-lib`, it can set the `enableDragAndDrop` prop to `true` and install `react-dnd`/`react-dnd-html5-backend`. If the DnD feature was not to going to be implemented, the extra dependencies would not be necessary as long as the `enableDragAndDrop` prop remained `false` or `undefined`.

This setup seems to work fine when the DnD dependencies *are* installed in the consuming application, but when they're not then I run into problems. I've only tried it with a Vite-based application, which uses esbuild for the dev server and Rollup for production builds. Both seem to have issues when dynamic imports fail.

For example, when running the app's dev server with vite, this error appears pointing to the `import('react-dnd')` line:

```
[plugin:vite:import-analysis] Failed to resolve import "react-dnd" from "node_modules\.vite\deps\my-react-component-lib.js?v=9969840a". Does the file exist?
```

Is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I ended up solving this problem was to publish a separate "dnd" package with `react-dnd` and `react-dnd-html5-backend` as `peerDependencies`.

The "dnd" package exports a React context provider that injects drag-and-drop functionality into the main package components, and it's completely optional. Implementation is like this:

```
import { MainDndContextProvider } from "@main-component/dnd";
import { MainComponent } from "main-component";

export const App = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <div id="dnd-disabled">
        {/* This does NOT have drag-and-drop features */}
        <MainComponent />
      </div>
      <div id="dnd-enabled">
        <MainDndContextProvider>
          {/* This DOES have drag-and-drop features */}
          <MainComponent />
        </MainDndContextProvider>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};
```

In order for the new context provider to use the right `react-dnd` instance, I had to make it a `peerDependencies` entry and not `dependencies`. So unfortunately users have to install `react-dnd` and `react-dnd-html5-backend` manually.

Also, `react-dnd` is asynchronously loaded with `import()`, which means the component is initially rendered with drag-and-drop disabled until the dependencies are loaded. I provided a workaround for that by allowing the `react-dnd` exports to be passed in through a prop to the context provider. That way they are loaded immediately.

For more information, see the [v5.0.0 entry in the changelog](https://github.com/react-querybuilder/react-querybuilder/blob/main/CHANGELOG.md#v500---2022-10-22) for [`react-querybuilder`](https://github.com/react-querybuilder/react-querybuilder/) ([main package code](https://github.com/react-querybuilder/react-querybuilder/tree/main/packages/react-querybuilder), [dnd code](https://github.com/react-querybuilder/react-querybuilder/tree/main/packages/dnd)).

Answer (score 1):

An alternative (not necessarily better) would be to let the user provide the library if needed:

```js
import { optionalLib } from 'optional-lib';
import { init } from 'your-lib';
init(optionalLib);
```

That avoids the dynamic import and optional dependencies (which are a very rare npm feature). However it requires more knowledge from the user and makes typing the code used from the dependency much harder.

Comment: Yeah, I was going to have something like that as an additional option. Users could directly render `MainComponentWithoutDndProvider` instead of `MainComponent`, as long as they wrapped it with their own `DndProvider` and passed in the exports from `react-dnd`. The `useReactDnD` Hook would take the DnD props in and avoid the dynamic import if possible.